# SQL Server adding the slashes to the date on the fly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to add some sort of mask to my data. Currently I have a query like this:

```
SELECT [EmployeeTC_No] AS "Employee TC#"
      ,[pye_nlast] AS "Name Last"
      ,[pye_nfirst] AS "Name First"
      ,[Dept] AS "Department"
      ,[pye_status] AS "Active"
      ,[HireDate] AS "Hire Date"
      ,[SeparationDate] AS "Separation Date"
  FROM [testing].[dbo].[testing]
```

The data in the hiredate and separationdate column shows as 09282015 but I need the dates to show the slash ("/") like 09/28/2015 is there any way to add some kind of mask on the fly for these?

Comment: Dates don't have a format in SQL Server, they are stored as a binary value. You can't change the "format" of it as it doesn't have one. Instead the format is defined by the presentation layer.

Comment: What type is your column SeparationDate?  I'm guessing varchar?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: varchar(9) is the data type

Comment: Why are you storing dates as a `varchar` @DavidBrierton? `09282015` isn't "before" `12312000`, nor is it "after" `06242019`, but it is according to your data. The date/time datatypes exist for a reason and you should be using them.

Comment: You could add a _computed column_ with the formatted value for each "date" column so that you don't need to fiddle about each time you need it.

Comment: I didnt set up the tables I am just trying to work with it the best I can since I was only given read capabilities. So I am trying to add the slashes to the query on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ideal, since you appear to not be storing dates as a date type. If they are varchars, and you want to just add slashes for presentation, you can insert them where needed. This is assuming you always have a 8char date:

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(your_col, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/')
```

Comment: what is stuff stuff?

Comment: @DavidBrierton Its a function to insert a string into another string. Google SQL Server Stuff

Answer (score 3):

What you really need to do is fix your datatype of your column. `varchar` is not a one size fits all data type and should not be used to store dates. Like I said, `09282015` is **not** "after" `06242019`, but according to your data, it is.

You can fix your data by doing the below:

```
USE testing;
GO

--Change the data to the ISO yyyyMMdd format
UPDATE dbo.testing
SET HireDate = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,STUFF(STUFF(SeparationDate,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),101),112),
    SeparationDate = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,STUFF(STUFF(SeparationDate,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),101),112);
GO

--Change the data types
ALTER TABLE dbo.testing ALTER COLUMN HireDate date;
ALTER TABLE dbo.testing ALTER COLUMN SeparationDate date;
GO

--And now you can select, and change the datatype to a format, with ease
SELECT [EmployeeTC_No] AS [Employee TC#],
       [pye_nlast] AS [Name Last],
       [pye_nfirst] AS [Name First],
       [Dept] AS [Department],
       [pye_status] AS [Active],
       CONVERT(varchar(10),[HireDate],101) AS [Hire Date],
       CONVERT(varchar(10),[SeparationDate],101) AS [Separation Date]
  FROM [testing].[dbo].[testing];
```