# SQL Server Varchar Military Date Format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server and in my database I have a date column of type `varchar` and has data like `04042011`. I am trying to write a query that is being used for another program and it is requesting the format in a military format such as `YYYY-MM-DD`. Is there any way to do this on the fly for `HireDate` and `SeparationDate`?

```
SELECT [EmployeeTC_No] AS "Employee TC #"
      ,[pye_nlast] AS "Name Last"
      ,[pye_nfirst] AS "Name First"
      ,[Dept] AS "Department"
      ,CASE WHEN [pye_status] = 'A' THEN 1 
       WHEN [pye_status] = 'T' THEN 0 
       ELSE NULL END AS "Active"
      ,[HireDate] AS "Hire Date"
      ,[SeparationDate] AS "Separation Date"
  FROM [OnBaseWorking].[dbo].[Employees]
  WHERE EmployeeTC_No != 'Not Assigned'
    AND LOWER(EmployeeTC_No) = LOWER('@primary')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I only have read rights. So I am hoping I can do this on the fly I know dates should not be data type `varchar` and should be data type date. But I have no control over this and just trying to do what I can.

Comment: You should be fixing your data type. There are date and time datatypes for a reason. `04042011` is not "after" `01012019`, but it is according to your data.

Comment: You will have to convert this to a datetime and then apply formatting. But really the formatting belongs in the presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: Pick a less ambiguous date  is this mmddyyyy or ddmmyyyy  ?

Comment: The program is requiring the format to be YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: But what is the current "format"?

Comment: The program isn't "requiring" the "format" to be `yyyy-MM-dd` it's requiring you to use the right data type. `yyyy-MM-dd` is an unambigious format for the `date` datatype.

Comment: MMDDYYYY in the database

Comment: I agree it should be date but I am not the creator to this nor do I have privileges to adjust it unfortunately. :(

Comment: Then speak to whomever can and get them to fix it. That is the real solution here. Fix X, not try and catter for Y.

Comment: I just realised that i recognised what I was about to answer with: why is this not a duplicate of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743797/sql-server-adding-the-slashes-to-the-date-on-the-fly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If truly 8 characters.  I would stress use try_convert() in case you have some bogus data.

```
Select try_convert(date,right(HierDate,4)+left(HierDate,4))
 From  YourTable
```

To Trap EMPTY values.  This will return a NULL and not 1900-01-01

```
Select try_convert(date,nullif(HierDate,'')+left(HierDate,4))
 From  YourTable
```

Comment: this is working but if the data has a blank field it automatically is putting `1900-01-01`

Comment: Why would it insert a date when it should be blank?

Comment: Because `CONVERT(date,'') = '1900-01-01'` @DavidBrierton. If you don't have a value it should be `NULL`, not `''`. Yet another reason why the data type choice is bad; as you can't store a "blank" value in any of the date & time data types.

Comment: @DavidBrierton Empty/Blank (not null) will convert to 1900-01-01.  Just replace the right(...) with right(nullif(HierDate,''),4)   This will force the null

Comment: is there a way around this? lol its so close. Larnu I understand I am dealing with the same frustration

Comment: The `STUFF` method in your previous question would actually not have the problem @DavidBrierton, as `TRY_CONVERT(date.'//',101)` will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the string from the [substrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that you want.

```
SUBSTRING(YourField, {The position that the year starts}, 4)
+'-'+
SUBSTRING(YourField, {The position that the month starts}, 2)
+'-'+
SUBSTRING(YourField, {The position that the day starts}, 2)
```